# Algebra but not a Lie Algebra.

Tags: lie-algebras

I'm looking for an example to show that there can be Algebras over a field $F$ of characteristic 2, which follows $[x,y] = -[y,x]$ and the Jacobi identity, but is not a Lie Algebra.

Comment: what extra condition does it have to satisfy to become a lie algebra?

Comment: It has to satisfy $[x,x] =0$ for all $x$ belonging to the Lie algebra

Comment: Like I understand what the problem is when the characteristic of the field is 2 for an abstract Lie algebra, but I can't think of a concrete example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basis $(u,v)$, law $uu=v$, $uv=vu=vv=0$.